# How to make sdk fetch the packages?

Tags: android, sdk

I live in Iran and my country is forbidden by google so the sdk can't fetch the packages
I used to get help from vpn and it used to work but now after i had changed my windows, it doesn't. Now when i use the vpn, it says done loading packages but it has loaded nothing. I used 5 vpn apps and differenet versions of SDK but that was in vain.
Can sb help me please? I really need the support libraries version 22.

Comment: i don't why your vpn would no longer be working. It is probably a matter of configuration

Comment: @njzk2 google is not forbidden by Iran. Iranian IPs are forbidden by google. I get 403 error

Comment: my bad the. what do you mean, your country is forbidden by google?

Comment: @njzk2 i mean google doesn't let the IP's from Iran use sdk and developer.android.com and even play store and microsoft doesn't let Iranians use windows store and it says store is not available in your region